# Proof for intersection.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, predicate-logic

Really stuck on this one, seemed simple but I just couldn't get it for some reason.

Suppose that $\mathcal U$ is the universal set, and that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are three arbitrary sets
of elements of $\mathcal U$. Prove that if $C \setminus A = B$, then the intersection of $A$ and $B$ is empty. Hint: use an indirect proof.

Comment: Indirect proof: suppose what you want to show is wrong, then find a contradiction

Comment: $A\cap B = A\cap(C\cap A^c) = \{\}$

Comment: Notice that if $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$, then $\exists x \in A \cap B$. Therefore, $x \notin C \setminus A$ so that $C \setminus A \neq B$. Therefore, if the two sets are equal then the intersection must be empty.

Comment: if you're satisfied with you're answer, then please click the green check to close the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show $C$ \ $A=B$ implies $A \cap B=\emptyset$.

Assume $A\cap B \not =  \emptyset.$

Then there is a $x$ s.t $x \in A$ and $x \in B$.

Since $x \in B$, and $C$ \ $A =B$ , we have $x \in C$\ $A,$

then $x \not \in A$, a contradiction.

Comment: This proof is not really indirect, though, depending on the definition of $\emptyset$. If you take $A \cap B = \emptyset :\Leftrightarrow \not\exists x \in A \cap B. x = x$ by definition, then the proof is in fact direct by negation introduction.

Comment: ComFreek.Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

**The following is a direct proof:**

$1$. Assume $C-A = B$

$2$. Then, by substitution,

$$A \cap B = A \cap \big(C-A \big)$$

$3$. By definition of set difference,

$$=A \cap \big(C \cap A^c\big)$$

$4$. By commutative law,

$$=A \cap \big(A^c \cap C\big)$$

$5$. By associative law,

$$=\big(A \cap A^c\big) \cap C$$

$6$. By negation law,

$$=\emptyset \cap C$$

$7$. By domination law,

$$=\emptyset$$

Therefore, if $C-A = B$, then $A \cap B = \emptyset$